# Question about finite dimensional representations of a semi-simple Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions, inner-product

I have posted a question in MSE
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4468138/question-about-finite-dimensional-representations-of-a-semi-simple-lie-group but didn't receive any comment or answer.

My question was the following:

I've encountered the following paragraph while reading  page 3 of this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01232026?noAccess=true

> Let $G$ be a semi-simple Lie group with a maximal compact subgroup $K$. Let $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{s}$ be the corresponding Cartan decomposition. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $G$  over $\mathbb{R}$.
> There exists a $K$-invariant inner product $(,)$ on $V$ such that any $X \in \mathfrak{s}$ acts as a symmetric operator.

I know that since $K$ is a compact subgroup, there exists a $K$-invariant inner product $(,)$ on $V$, but I don't know why there is such an inner product for which every $X \in \mathfrak{s}$ acts as a symmetric operator ? Any help please.

Comment: This is well known and is in Helgason's book. In the complexification $\mathfrak g _{\mathbb C}$ of $\mathfrak g$, you have the real subalgebra $\mathfrak k \oplus i \mathfrak p$, which can be seen to be a "compact Lie algebra"; it is the Lie algebra of a compact group $U$ in $G(\mathbb C)$. The representation $V$ extends to a complex representation of $G(\mathbb C)$; $U$ being compact, its lie algebra elements act by skew symmetric matrices with respect to a suitable $U$ invariant Hermitian metric on $V\otimes {\mathbb C}$. Hence $\mathfrak p$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @Venkataramana